# Plotting vector field using StreamPlot of VectorPlot doesn't work properly in some cases

Tags: plotting, vector

I tried to plot a vector field in a determined region by two methods: 1- VectorPlot and 2-StreamPlot:

```
u = beta (x)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2));
v = beta (y)/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2));
VectorPlot[{u, v}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
StreamPlot[{u, v}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

The problem is that, in the first case, it plots all vectors in the same magnitude. In the second case, it plots only one vector! 
I guess the reason for the problem could be that u and v become infinite in position(0 and 0). But I don't know how to ignore this point when plotting. Do anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding `VectorPoints -> 5` to your `VectorPlot` to plot more than one vector. Adjust the number of points to suit.

Comment: What's beta?  And your formulas have unbalanced parentheses, so it's to be sure what your intent is.